# ExtJs Tree loading sequence

Tags: javascript, extjs, tree

Good day.

I am writing a tree control with **Ext.tree.Panel**, which loads its configuration from external .json file, while data  is being loaded as .json from the server.

So, I've got the view like this:

```
Ext.define('App.tree.TreeView', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    ...
    initFilters: function(cfg) {
        /*several this.store.addFilter() based on cfg*/
    },   
    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        me.cfg = getSomeCfgFromSomewhere();
        me.initFilters(me.cfg);
    }    
});
```

The store:

```
Ext.define('Site.widgets.tree.TreeStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    ...
    proxy: { 
        type: App.cfg.proxy, 
        reader: { type: 'json', rootProperty: 'data.children' }, 
        format: App.cfg.proxy.urlEnd, 
        url: App.cfg.treeRoot, 
        noCache: false
    }
    lazyFill: true,

    rootVisible: true,
    root: {
        full_path: '/', /*set as idProperty in model*/
        'display-name': 'root',
        expanded: true
    },
});
```

The problem is: my root is explicitly set in the store, which loads its contents because of **expanded: true**. But then only these contents are shown in the tree, without the root itself. When filtering is removed, the tre is loaded OK.

Possible reason: from debugging of Sencha code in ext-all-debug.js: view's **initComponent** is called before the store starts loading the data, therefore it adds filters before the data is loaded, when the root is still empty, and then calls

```
onNodeFilter: function(root, childNodes) {
    var me = this,
        data = me.getData(),
        toAdd = [];
    if (me.getRootVisible()) {
        if (childNodes.length) {
            toAdd.push(root);
        } else {
            root.set('visible', false, me._silentOptions);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

, i.e. the root is set invisible because it is still empty, and only then root's children are loaded.

The question is: is there an initial design mistake in my filters initialisation, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the problem is that view's initComponent is called before the store starts loading the data, I would try:

**Calling initFilters inside store load event, like this:**

```
Ext.define('Site.widgets.tree.TreeStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    ...
    proxy: { 
        type: App.cfg.proxy, 
        reader: { type: 'json', rootProperty: 'data.children' }, 
        format: App.cfg.proxy.urlEnd, 
        url: App.cfg.treeRoot, 
        noCache: false
    }
    lazyFill: true,

    rootVisible: true,
    root: {
        full_path: '/', /*set as idProperty in model*/
        'display-name': 'root',
        expanded: true
    },
    listeners : {
        load : function() {
             //Call initFilters. 
             //initFilters should call addFilter just once, 
             //with array of filters as first parameter, 
             //to avoid filtering the hole tree more than once!
        }
    }
});
```

This approach has a problem, because you have to deal with initFilters cfg parameter scope.

Comment: The backend returns a node defined by the path contained in **full_path** member of the node, thus the tree is loaded dynamically. The root has to describe the 'upper' node of the subtree I want to load and later I want to be able to change it from outside. My proxy actually looks like this: `proxy: { type: App.cfg.proxy, reader: { type: 'json', rootProperty: 'data.children' }, format: App.cfg.proxy.urlEnd, url: Site.cfg.url.treeRoot, noCache: false }`

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. The first thing I have tried myself, but it didn't change the behaviour. The second one may work, but initialising the filters at any load event seems to be quite an expensive fix, since every one of them calls filtering of the whole tree, and there are usually about 6 filters.

Comment: You are welcome! The method addFilter accepts an array of filters as first parameter, so you can call it just once!

Comment: Oh, ok, fixed filters initialisation in my code, thanks. Tried to do this the second way you posted - and it worked! Still, this does it on every load, while I would prefer to do it just once on initialisation, but nevertheless I should upvote your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, turned out that part of the answer was just inside the question: I was able to fix this thing by simply overloading `onNodeFilter()` method inside my store, since I know that I want to always show the root. If anyone could advise anything better - be my guest, please.

Comment: Nice, at least you found the solution!  =)